# How to create column with maximum function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The formula is `Max MOB 2` is maximum between `MOB 1` and `MOB 2`, then  `Max MOB 3` is maximum among `MOB 1`, `MOB 2`, and `MOB 3`, for make it easier, here's my data set

```
User_id   MOB 1    MOB 2   MOB 3   MOB 4
1             0        4       1       1
2            -2        6       5       1
3             4        1       6       2
```

My expected output

```
   User_id   Max MOB 1    Max MOB 2   Max MOB 3   Max MOB 4
    1                0            4           4           4
    2               -2            6           6           6
    3                4            1           6           6
```

What I already try is `due_table['Max MOB 2'] = max(due_table['MOB 1'],due_table['MOB 2'])` but fail

The error is `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`, so I guess `max` function cann't durecty in pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `cummax`

```
out = df.set_index('User_id').cummax(1).add_prefix('Max ')
```